# Restricting loess' multicore usage in R

Tags: r, multithreading, cpu-cores, loess

I'm trying to fit +- 70.000 values as a function of two variables using the `loess()` function several times. I want to use this fit to de-trend the data. My problem is that once I start the loess function, the R session takes up all available cores on the system, and that would be inconsiderate towards other users on the same computing cluster.

The relevant code would be analogous to the following:

```
# Approximation of the data
df <- data.frame(y = rpois(70000, rnorm(70000, 10, 2)), # y is count data
                 x = 50000 - rpois(70000, 100),
                 z = runif(70000))

# The problematic operation
fit <- loess(y ~ x + z, data = df)
```

When I run this example on my local machine, it only takes up 1 core, but on the cluster it takes as many cores as it could get (up to 48). Ideally, I would `loess()` to run on only 1 core.

I've tried to trace any multicore parameters in the code of loess, which I couldn't find. I know that loess calls `stats:::simpleLoess`, which in turn calls [C code](https://github.com/SurajGupta/r-source/blob/master/src/library/stats/src/loessc.c), which in turn calls [Fortran](https://github.com/SurajGupta/r-source/blob/master/src/library/stats/src/loessf.f) code. I have no experience in C or Fortran and I haven't been able to figure out how I can restrict the CPU usage for this function.

Does anyone has any suggestion on how I can limit the CPU usage of the loess function?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am not knowledgeable enough to comment on specifics about how all of this works, but I know that C++ and FORTRAN for R are usually built using the [OpenMP framework](https://www.openmp.org) for multi-thread programming. Empirically, I do know that your issue can be resolved if you set the `OMP_NUM_THREADS` argument before you launch R or if you set it within an R session.

Let's say you wanted to use 2 threads for the `loess` function. Before you launch R, you would do this (`$` to signify typing this in a shell session):

```
$ OMP_NUM_THREADS=2 R [whatever other options you use to launch R]
```

Here's how to do it from within R (`>` to indicate an interactive R session):

```
> Sys.setenv("OMP_NUM_THREADS" = 2)
```

If you ever need to check the variable from within R, you can do the following (this will return a character vector with the number):

```
> Sys.getenv("OMP_NUM_THREADS")
# The result in our example will be "2"
```

For completeness, be sure to use `?Sys.setenv` or `?Sys.getenv` if you wish to get more information about those functions, and check out [this site](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSGH2K_13.1.0/com.ibm.xlc131.aix.doc/compiler_ref/ruomprun4.html) for details about `OMP_NUM_THREADS`.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 2):

So McG led me down a path that eventually gave me the ability to control the number of cores, which I'll post as another answer.

There were a few details I foolishly neglected to mention, namely that I was working on an RStudio server. For all other purposes, I indeed think that McG's answer would be excellent.

That answer helped me get the correct terms to google, and strolling around the search results I stumbled upon this [thread](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-sig-debian/2016-August/002588.html) that suggested that the `RhpcBLASctl` package has a function to set the number of cores as follows:

```
blas_set_num_threads(2)
```

Setting this in an RMarkdown document before running `loess` kept my CPU usage at 200% while running the `loess` function afterwards that was problematic before.